# FTPClient Java из org.apache искажает изображение после загрузки

Tags: ftp, java, upload, изображения

Код ниже где-то нашёл. Часть изображений заливает на отлично, а часть портит, может не успевает или еще что, но во времени метод не ограничиваю. На залитом изображении, например, часть пикселей ( обычно прямоугольник ) либо светлее, либо темнее, других.

public void saveToFtp(String image){

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
FileInputStream fis = null;

try {
    client.connect("x.x.x.x");
    client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    client.login("login", "password");

    String filename = "images/"+image;
    fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
    System.out.println(fis.available());

    client.changeWorkingDirectory("public_html/big");
    client.storeFile(image, fis);

    client.logout();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
        client.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: ... и вы хотите, чтобы мы за вас разобрались в коде, который вы не писали, и сами не хотите разобраться?

Проверьте на выброс исключения. Проверьте, выполняется ли код до конца. Пройдитесь под отладчиком. Добавьте отладочную печать. Сверьте размер и содержимое локального и принятого файлов.

Сделайте что-нибудь сами. Нам лень.

Comment: Я разбирался с ним, и с первого раза он не взлетал, да. Под где-то нашёл не имелось ввиду, что я просто взял метод и залепил его в свой код.
Размер нового изображение естественно другой, ReplyCode после заливки 226

Comment: И да, 226 - Закрытие канала, обмен завершен успешно

Исключений не выбрасывает

Comment: Так, хорошо. А содержимое? Начальная часть передаётся правильно? Затем, а где в приведённом коде ReplyCode? Вы убедились, что код добегает до конца (до `client.logout();`)? Какое значение возвращает `client.storeFile()`?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/wJGyhsR.png вот пример битой части изображения
До storeFile идёт ReplyCode 230 (Пользователь идентифицирован, продолжайте), после него 226, про который писал выше. Про добегание до client.logout - проверил, доходит. StoreFile возвращает true.

Comment: @Sn0wSky27: Хм. Попробуйте binary diff между тем, что есть, и тем, что передалось. Может быть, не сработало переключение в binary mode? такое впечатление, что попортились единичные байты, это может быть из-за ASCII-mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по всему, у вас та же проблема, что и в [этом вопросе на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3145768/276994): вы чересчур рано переключаетесь в бинарный режим.

Вы должны переключиться в бинарный режим *после* логина, иначе режим сбрасывается в ASCII, и байты вокруг «концов строк» (то есть, символов 0x0D или 0x0A) портятся.

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, именно то, что и надо было, перекинул переключение на бинарный за логин и всё пошло!

Comment: @Sn0wSky27: Вот и отлично, минус одна проблема.